# How to connect using Oracle Client 12 that I just installed using TOAD?

Tags: oracle, client, toad

I have installed Oracle Client 12.1.0. I want to connect to database using this new client. However, I only see my old Oracle Client 11.1.0 on the 'Connect Using' box. I do not see 12.1.0 as Installed Client in the TOAD connect window.

I have tried adding C:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1 to PATH variable. My system variable does not have ORACLE_HOME.

I see following when I click the three ... in the TOAD connect window.

```
OraClient11g_home1 (11.1.0.6)
    ORACLE_HOME:C:\oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1
    ORACLE_HOME_NAME:OraClient11g_home1
    ORACLE_HOME_KEY:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1
    ORACLE_SID:
    NLS_LANG:AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
    SQLPATH:C:\oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\dbs
    LOCAL:
    Client DLL:C:\oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll
    TNSNames.ora:C:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
    SQLNet.ora:C:\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
    LDAP.ora:
    Login.sql:
    GLogin.sql:C:\oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql
    In system PATH:Yes
    Home is valid:Yes
```

Please advise me what I need to change to be able to connect using Oracle 12 client.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you install the 64-bit version of Oracle Client? Is your TOAD 32-bit? The architecture has to be the same.

Comment: Instant Client 19.3 is available.  For Oracle Call Interface programs you can use this to connect to Oracle DB 11.2 or later.